# Edit Item in the Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm building a project to order pizza, and I want to edit the toppings of the pizza in a specific order.

I have a button to select toppings. The button changes to blue when I click on it.

My problem is what to do add to the return, to select button topping and the blue button stay blue.

for example I choose topping of onion and olive and their buttons are now blue, and when I want to change my choices, I want the button of onion and olive to stay blue.

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appButton]'
})
export class ButtonDirective  {

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }
@HostListener('mousedown') onmousedown() {
   if (this.elRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
    // console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement);
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'rgba(200,0,0,0.7)');
   } else {
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');

   }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="row choiceBoxTopping" style="position: relative; top: 90px; padding-top: 10px ">
  <p style="padding-left: 10px">Please choose a Topping</p>
  <app-button *ngFor="let topping of toppings; let i = index"
              [topping]="topping"
              [index]="i"></app-button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style=" position:absolute; bottom: 7px; right: 20px" (click)="onContinue()">Continue</button>
</div>
```

**html  app-button**

```
    <div class="col-md-4" style= "padding-top: 10px;">
    <button id="top" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  style="width: 110px" appButton (click)= "onClickDown()"  >
      {{topping.name}}
    </button>
    </div>
```

**ts**

```
  onContinue() {

    this.carts = new Cart(this.mealService.getPizzaName(),
      this.mealService.getOrderChoosePrice(), this.mealService.getTopping());
    this.orderService.addItemCart(this.carts);
   }
```

**service**

```
public addItemCart(cart: Cart) {
  this.cart.push(cart);
  this.cartChanged.next(this.cart.slice());
  this.price += cart.price;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more? Do you mean when going back to choose other things the blue color is lost?

Comment: I have a pizza ordering list with topping I want to re-edit the pizza  topping and I want when I edit the topping buttons already selected before editing to be blue and everything else is red

Comment: Check the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the list of toppings saved in the cart, you can add the styles using it.
So when the topping is selected, the you it will be blue, otherwise, it will be red. This can be done using classes.

You can go over the toppings before in ngOnInit, and add a `selected` field to it

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.toppings = this.toppings
    // Create new array with selected field;
    .map(topping => {
      // Check if the topping is selected
      const isSelected = this.mealService.getTopping()
        .some(selectedTopping => topping.name === selectedTopping.name);
      topping.selected = isSelected;
      return topping; 
    })
}
```

In the stylesheet:

```
.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

in the template:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style= "padding-top: 10px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn"  style="width: 110px" (click)= "onClickDown(topping)" 
    [ngClass]="{'red': !topping.selected, 'blue': topping.selected }" >
  {{topping.name}}
  </button>
</div>
```

And in the `onClickDown` function, you can change the `selected` flag

```
onClickDown(topping) {
  topping.selected = !topping.selected;
}
```